# How to include my own library .so file in android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I want to build a shared library that uses OpenCv library inside it. So I wrote my code in c++ and test it on mac OsX and everything work great. Now I want to use my library in android for some image processing stuff.

so I download OpenCv3.4.7 Android SDK. There is a libopencv_java3.so file inside it for armeabi-v7a architecture.
So I built my own library with OpenCv shared library, finally I could get my libscanner.so file.

Here is my CmakeList.txt for scanner library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

if (" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL " ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.
       You should create a separate directory for build files.")
endif ()

project(scanner)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(SCANNER_SOURCES business/ImageProcessor.cpp
        util/ContoursUtil.cpp
        Predictor.cpp)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
add_library(scanner SHARED ${SCANNER_SOURCES})

set(OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR /Users/shayantabatabaei/Downloads/OpenCv3.4.7/sdk/native/jni/include)
set(OPENCV_LIB_DIR /Users/shayantabatabaei/Downloads/OpenCv3.4.7/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so)
include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(scanner ${OPENCV_LIB_DIR})

install(FILES Predictor.h
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

and I build my 'scanner' library for android using this command :

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-28 -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$(pwd) -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a;
```

so finally after all these process I could get my libscanner.so file.
I want to use all of these in android so I created android studio project with c++ support and here is my cmakeList.txt file in android :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)

target_include_directories(native-lib PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Predictor.h)

set(SHARED_LIB_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI})

find_library(jnigraphics-lib jnigraphics)
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${SHARED_LIB_PATH}/libscanner.so ${SHARED_LIB_PATH}/libopencv_java3.so)
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${jnigraphics-lib})
```

and I placed 'libscanner.so' and 'libopencv_java3.so' under app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a folder.

Android application will compile but crashes in runtime. I also checked my apk with apk alanyzer and my libraries was packed into apk file.

here is the crashes log :

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2019-07-30 11:55:58.329 14182-14182/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x23 in tid 14182 (tcardscannerapp), pid 14182 (tcardscannerapp)
2019-07-30 11:55:58.397 14212-14212/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2019-07-30 11:55:58.398 2989-2989/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 14182
2019-07-30 11:55:58.399 14212-14212/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 14182 (target tid = 14182)
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j6ltedx/j6lte:9/PPR1.180610.011/J600GDXU4BSF2:user/release-keys'
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '2'
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: pid: 14182, tid: 14182, name: tcardscannerapp  >>> com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp <<<
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x23
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     r0  fffae858  r1  ffffffff  r2  00000018  r3  fffae828
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     r4  fffae764  r5  fffae810  r6  eb774d94  r7  fffae758
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     r8  fffae858  r9  d05b3028  r10 00000000  r11 00000001
2019-07-30 11:55:58.423 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     ip  00000000  sp  fffae750  lr  d01843bf  pc  d01845a6
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0006f5a6  /data/app/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp-UaIZuU0t8ZmOytvA0JtT4A==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0006f3bb  /data/app/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp-UaIZuU0t8ZmOytvA0JtT4A==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0006cd79  /data/app/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp-UaIZuU0t8ZmOytvA0JtT4A==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0006cc2f  /data/app/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp-UaIZuU0t8ZmOytvA0JtT4A==/lib/arm/libc++_shared.so (__gxx_personality_v0+78)
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 008f032d  /data/app/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp-UaIZuU0t8ZmOytvA0JtT4A==/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException+64)
2019-07-30 11:55:58.427 14212-14212/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 008f0a8f  /data/app/com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp-UaIZuU0t8ZmOytvA0JtT4A==/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_Unwind_RaiseException+22)
2019-07-30 11:55:58.776 2989-2989/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
2019-07-30 11:55:58.778 3300-14215/? W/ActivityManager: crash : com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp,0
2019-07-30 11:55:58.779 3300-14215/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.tosan.creditcardscannerapp/.MainActivity
```

the crash log is weird to me since I have no experience in c++, would anyone help me to come through this problem ?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Your crash log shows that the opencv library has been successfully loaded for your Android app. At the same time, it looks weird, because official OpenCV 3.4.7 is built with `c++_static` STL, but your log shows **libc++_shared.so**.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Thank you, and yesy libc++_shared.so also is packed within my apk. I use these arguments in my build.gradle file : `"-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared", "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-28"`

Comment: It's not healthy that **libopencv_java3.so** calls into **libc++_shared.so**. Maybe if you try to build your own libs with `c++_static`, you will know more about the problem. But, unfortunately, I don't expect this to resolve the unhandled exception in OpenCV that is at the bottom (root) of your crash.